# "Робити мерву" - в значені "робити безлад"

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, фразеологізми

В дитинстві мама часто казала: "Не робіть мерву в хаті", що означало "не робіть безлад". 
В СУМ-11 знайшла значення

> [Мерва](http://sum.in.ua/s/merva)  и, жін., діал. М'ята, терта або зопріла солома.

З данного визначення не зрозуміло який зв'язок "робити мерву" з "безладом". Цікавить, як саме виник вираз "робити мерву"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заглянемо у [ЕСУМ](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1989/EtSlUkrM_1989.pdf) (439 ст. ПДФ), слово "мерва" може означати не лише: "М'ята, терта або зопріла солома", а й - "дрантя, погань, болото", а також є синонімом до слова "шовковиця" (крім цього є ця інформація ще й [тут](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/28066-merva.html)). Також саме слово споріднене із литовським "marva" (мішанина) та "merja" (подробити, розтовкти). Можу припустити, що можливо в якомусь регіоні слово "мерва" могло мати діалектне значення "мішанина" (яке могло з'явитися, наприклад, під час правління Литовського князівства на український землях), а тому й не дивно, що кажуть "не робіть мерву", адже "[мішанина](http://sum.in.ua/s/mishanyna)" - це відсутність порядку, плутанина, безладдя. Однак, це лише моє припущення.

Ось [Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови (ВТССУМ)](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-84238.htm):

> -а, с., діал.:
>
> ••
>
> Мерво робити — чинити скандал.

Таку ж інформацію знайшов на цьому форумі, а ще там вказується, що слово "мерва" може вживатися у значенні "безлад, хаос", однак всі силки, які там даються не працюють, тому складно говорити про достовірність всієї інформації. Однак, там наводиться вживання слова "мерва" у значенні "скандал":

> Ти ж маленька ніжність, підліткове стерво, 
>   Віддалась огидна крізь облуду фраз, 
>   Мама взнає – зробить тобі справжнє мерво,
>   Але ж ти говориш: «…було, і не раз!

І ще одне моє припущення - як я вже писав, одне із значень цього слова - "болото" або й навіть "калюжа в якій валяються свині" ([джерело](http://www.volynpost.com/news/83158-kukuriky-ta-sushybaba-kumedni-nazvy-volynskyh-sil)). Можливо слово "мерва" у вислові "робити мерву" має саме це значення (тобто виходить щось на кшталт "не робіть із хати сарай").

Про те, що одним із діалектних значень слова "мерва" може бути "хаос та безлад" можна також знайти у "[Волинському діалекті Привілійщини](https://archive.org/stream/mvv948_gmail_20171205/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%92-%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_djvu.txt)" В. Михальчука.

Answer (score 1):

- [Словник Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/28066-merva.html):

  > Ме́рва, -ви, ж. 1) Мятая, тертая негодная солома. На городі мерва. Грин. III. 659. 2) Дрянь, негодное. 3) мн. = морва.
- З мертвого [форуму](http://www.litforum.net.ua/showthread.php?p=58578):

  > Мерво - це безлад, хаос. це слово я ніколи не намагався шукати в словниках))) просто користувався завжди. з батьківських уст
- З [вірша Юрія Матевощука](http://maysterni.com/publication.php?id=59330):

  > Ти ж маленька ніжність, підліткове стерво,
  >   Віддалась, огидна, крізь облуду фраз,
  >   Мама взнає — зробить тобі справжнє мерво,
  >   Але ж ти говориш: «Було і не раз!…».

<sub>Див. також: [обговорення на форумі slovnyk.ua](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=2768).</sub>